# Python Subprocess - variable types?

Tags: python, shell, variables, unix, subprocess

I'm working a python code that uses some programs accessible only from my Unix terminal (Windows 7 OS, using a putty terminal) I have already looked at countless articles, I know that similar questions have been asked but nothing is working for me.

This is the code

```
#written in Py 2.7

from subprocess import call

subject = open ('test_file1', 'r')
target =open ('test_file2', 'r')
output = open ('output_test.bla8', 'w')
call(['blat', '-prot', '-minScore=0', '-stepSize=5', '-repMatch=2253', '-minIdentity=0', '-out=blast8', subject, target, output])
subject.close()
target.close()
output.close()
```

The error I receive is this:

```
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

So a bit of explanation, "blat" is the program I am calling, all the -flags are arguments that I want to pass to the blat program and the last three statements are also arguments that I need to get to program but they actually specify files for the program to read/write.

Is there a way to pass argument values to a shell command that are actually files if not using 'subprocess.call'?? Surely there is a simple way to accomplish this, that as I beginner I'm just not aware of. By the way I have had a glance at the subprocess docs, but as a newbie I still can't quite get it http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

THANKS!!!

Comment: Is `blat` meant to take file names or handles?  My bet is the problem is that you are passing file objects in the list of command components to `call` and it expects only strings.  Are you looking for the `stdin` and `stdout` kwargs?

Comment: Yes, your hunch was correct. The call function will only take strings. I don't think it is possible to do what I was attempting. I got around the issue by creating a list of the input files I need and then feeding them to the call() with an index look up (code is below as a new answer). Thanks, Silas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

`f = open('file','r')`

your **Python** process is opening the file and storing the file handle/object in f.  This open file handle/object cannot be put on a commandline (you can't type it), so you are getting an error from `call`, which takes commandline arguments.

If your 'blat' program takes filenames and opens the file in its own process, you should just remove the `open` calls and just put the filenames directly into the `call` call.  If that's not what blat does, than you need to understand how it gets its data and pass it in that form.

Comment: Your question gave me just the inspiration I needed. You're correct that blat can open files via its own processes. I need to use a varaible though, rather than hard-coding the file handle however, because eventually I want to build a loop that will run this blat program on many files. I solved the issue using your suggestions though- the code is below. Its so simple, why didn't I think of it before?!  Thank you Peter!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using this code:

```
new_list= []
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.fa'):
    new_list.append(file)

input_file1 = new_list[0]
input_file2 = new_list[1]
blat =call(['blat', '-prot', '-minScore=0', '-stepSize=5', '-repMatch=2253', 'minIdentity=0', '-out=blast8', input_file1 , input_file1, 'output_test'])
```